# set default proxy programmatically instead of using app.config

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Being behind a proxy, my .Net 4.0 C# application only works when there is an app.config with the following content:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy />
        <bypasslist />
        <module />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Now since I don't want to have an app.config and since embedding app.config is not recommended, what is the C# code that has the same effect as that xml chunk in the app.config and where do I place it?

Comment: I need a solution to this problem so bad!! I've been consistently hitting this problem in a number of environments for years now...

Answer (score 18):

You can use [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) or [GlobalProxySelection.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.globalproxyselection.aspx)

```
System.Net.GlobalProxySelection.Select = new WebProxy(ip,port);
```

OR

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy(ip,port);
```

Comment: System.Net.GlobalProxySelection is deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

The following code worked for me:

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials 
    = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `WebProxy` from `System.Net`

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("PROXYIP",PORTNO);
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
req.Proxy = proxyObject;
```

[More details at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx)

Comment: This would not change the proxy for the whole app like the app.config would, just this single request.